# Assigning an image to a SKShapeNode as a Ball - Spritekit Game

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, sprite, skshapenode

I am trying to add an image to my ball in my Swift 2 Sprite-kit game. I have a `make()` ball function and it there are no errors there however in the game scene, when the method is called, I keep receiving this error :

**"Cannot assign SKShapeNode' to type Ball!**

I am not sure how to fix and am new to Swift.

```
// ----- GameScene.Swift ----
class GameScene: SKScene, GameDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   // ball part one
   var ball: Ball!
   let ballSpeedX = CGFloat(500)
}

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // ball
    ball = Ball.make() // error!!!
    ball.position.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
    ball.position.y = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)
    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollideType.Ball.toMask()
    ball.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollideType.toMask([.Scene, .Ceil, .Floor]) | boards.usedCollideMasks
    ball.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollideType.toMask([.Scene, .Ceil, .Floor]) | boards.usedCollideMasks
    ball.hidden = true
    self.addChild(ball)
 }
```

And this is **Ball.swift** where the `make()` is:

```
//Ball. Swift

//imports...

class Ball: SKShapeNode {

  var speedXFirst = CGFloat(0)
var speedXSecond = CGFloat(0)
var lastFloor = -1

var xSpeed: CGFloat {
    get {
        return speedXFirst + speedXSecond
    }
}

var lastBoardNumber = 0

private override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

static func make()-> SKShapeNode {

    let textureBall : SKTexture! = SKTexture(imageNamed:"colorBall.png")
    let ballSize: CGSize = textureBall.size()
    var ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: ballSize.width/2)
    ball.fillTexture = textureBall
    ball.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    ball.name = "ball"
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor() // use the color you want
    return ball
 }

 func freezeX() {
    self.speedXFirst = 0
    self.speedXSecond = 0
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you try to assign a regular initialized and customized `SKShapeNode` (built by your `make()` method) to a type `Ball` that isn't the same `SKShapeNode` type (subclassed with a specific init).

You could customized your **Ball** class like this:

```
class Ball: SKShapeNode {
    var speedXFirst = CGFloat(0)
    var speedXSecond = CGFloat(0)
    var lastFloor = -1
    private var radius: CGFloat!

    var xSpeed: CGFloat {
        get {
            return speedXFirst + speedXSecond
        }
    }
    var lastBoardNumber = 0

    init(imageNamed: String){
        super.init()
        let textureBall : SKTexture! = SKTexture.init(imageNamed:imageNamed)
        let ballSize: CGSize = textureBall.size()
        self.radius = ballSize.width/2
        self.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: radius*2, height: radius*2)), nil)
        self.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.name = "ball"
        self.zPosition = 1
        self.fillTexture = textureBall
        self.fillColor = UIColor.redColor() // use the color you want
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func freezeX() {
        self.speedXFirst = 0
        self.speedXSecond = 0
    }
}
```

So when you are in your scene you can call it like this:

```
var ball: Ball!
ball = Ball(imageNamed:"colorBall.png")
```

Comment: thanks, with all of this code, in my game scene  `ball = Ball(imageNamed:"colorBall.png")` throws error: Expected declaration.

Comment: i did, I also did the gamescene and it throws that expected declaration error

Comment: Very strange, probably you have some another issue. If it can be useful download the project from here http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04551335866809243939

Comment: Update: I opened that project and noticed a mistake I made, I fixed it and when I run it, it makes it to the launch screen and throws this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, tried deleting the ! after ball but that caused 'no initilizers' error

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand because I've the project in running correctly, you speak about my project or your project? Have you declare the var ball: Ball! ?

Comment: my project, i have it declared like you, `var ball: Ball!`

Comment: Ok, the unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping come from the physicsBody right? It's come because you haven't initialize the physicBody of your object, but in your code you try to directly fill the properties like categoryBitMask, i dont use these lines in my project , I've commented it

Comment: Proceed by steps, fix your Ball.swift, after that run and if it's ok after think to how to build the physicBody :)

Comment: ah yes, its from the physicsBody, is there a way to fix that? All of the physics in my game are a problem now, I commented out similar to you in ball, but when touches began it crashes.

Comment: Ok, so this issue is solved. If you have another issues like touchesBegan or PhysicsBody initialization please open new questions so the people who read this question title can see only all the answers about it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your amazing. i opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280426/unwrapping-optional-values-physicsbody-swift-spritekit

Comment: @N.Howey seems anyone considered your new question in link as a duplicate link to a remote question that has nothing to do with Sprite-Kit and your request, change the question content to avoid closure.